# C# burning DVD+-VR with IMAPI2

Tags: c#, dvd

I would like to find some information about DVD+-VR with IMAPI2. I guess it is possible to create and burning DVD-VR with IMAPI2 but I can not find examples how to do.

Do you have some idea or some example code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, but it is no question about recommend or find a tool. I want to use IMAPI2 but I only don't know which class or interface to use for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following C# [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/) articles:

1. [Burning and Erasing CD/DVD/Blu-ray Media with C# and IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an), By Eric Haddan.

   Creating a tool with the basic functionality of Nero Burning Room.
2. [How to Create Optical File Images using IMAPIv2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23653/How-to-Create-Optical-File-Images-using-IMAPIv2-0), By dmihailescu. 

   Example on how to create and burn [ISO image files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image).
3. [Creating Audio CDs using IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25241/Creating-Audio-CDs-using-IMAPI2), By Eric Haddan. 

   Shows how to use [IDiscFormat2TrackAtOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface for creating audio CDs.